# Python logging.conf reload configuration

Tags: python, logging, filter, configuration, handler

in my python code I read the logging configuration from a file where I have put the format I would like to have in my code.
When I try to reload the configuration at runtime it seems that the set of some extra env I put in my formatters are lost and I have the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 861, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'hostname'
Logged from file conn.py, line 304
```

To notice that my logging.conf is the following:

```
[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s [ThId-%(threadName)-10s] [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s] [%(hostname)s] %(message)s
datefmt=%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p
```

where **hostname** is set in the code via:

```
class HostnameFilter(logging.Filter):
    hostname = platform.node()

    def filter(self, record):
        record.hostname = HostnameFilter.hostname
        return True

## Log Logger.
class Logger:
    """!@brief
    Logger wrapper
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger("MYCONF")
        self.log.addFilter(HostnameFilter())
```

The weird thing is that the errors seems to appear in classes (conn.py) not mine, maybe this is the code of some libraries I am using that are logging as well.

Is this the flow? Shall I do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because formatting happens in handlers, and events logged to a logger are passed to handlers of that logger and to handlers further up the logger hierarchy, you'd need to be sure that the `hostname` attribute is always added to the record - which may not be the case if a different logger is used to log the message. Try attaching the filter to the relevant handler(s) rather than logger(s).